# Python sklearn OCR for survey answers with special characters (✔ and ✗)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-imaging-library, ocr

I have several thousand of images in the format seen in this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaS7v.jpg and I'm looking for a method to convert this into a simple table in which ✓ = 1, - = 0 and ✗ = -1.

I tried text recognition software like Adobe without success.
Now I'm considering the sklearn Python module. So far I've managed to load the image into Python and turn it into a numpy array and I uploaded some correct results and turned it into an array aswell (looks like this: `[['0', '1', '1'], ['-1', '1', '1'], ... , ['0', '1', '1']]`)
.

```
import csv
from PIL import Image
import numpy
im = Image.open("training_image.png")
training_data = numpy.array(im)
with open('correct_results.csv', 'rb') as f:
    correct_results = list(csv.reader(f))
```

For what I can see, the sklearn process seems to always go the same way:

```
#Import a model: 
model=some_model()

#train it: 
model.fit(training_data,correct_results)

#predict:  
predicted_results=model.predict(new_input_data)
```

Now I would like to know, how I can transform this numpy array into a form that can be used by model.fit, and which model could I use for this? So far I had no success with my research.

Comment: A simple and hacky way would be to just count the black pixels. Before you do that, though, you need to come up with a method to split up an image of a table into the individual cells.

Comment: Should be manageable using the crop method of the PIL module. I guess no sklearn is needed then :)

Comment: I just realized the rows do not have a fixed vertical distance, since they are next to survey questions of different lengths (rows) ... So splitting it up into individual cells is not as simple